# Controlling the scrolling of an ASP.Net Listbox with the Rows attribute

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, scroll, listbox

So I have this plain jane Listbox control that is filled with entries from a DB on page init. Now by default it comes with a Rows count/Size attribute of 4. I have this control wrapped in a div that is set to the left and 100% height, with page scrolling disabled so that everything is on a single non-scrolling page.

With the default settings if you click on any entry greater than 4 the listbox will scroll to put what you clicked on in the 4th position in the box, this also causes my event.target object to point back to the select element instead of the clicked option element, preventing processing based on what was clicked (for clarity this is on the client side js). This holds until you've scrolled all the way to the bottom at which point you can click on anything displayed in the listbox.

If I set this to the number of available records you can click on anything in the first "page" of items and it will work fine, but if you scroll and try to click any item not in the first displayed set (by even 1 item) as soon as you click on it the Listbox will scroll back to the top, and the save event.target object issue shows itself. If you try using the arrow keys to navigate, highlighting will change but the Listbox will remain scrolled at the top and you can't see it.

If I set to the exact number of items that I can see on my screen when it is rendered it works exactly as I would expect. I can click on any entry at the top or scrolled to and all events fire, everything loads all is happy. That is all great but only works for my particular browser height.

I have AutoPostback turned off, have tried MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback set to true, and am now in the process of trying to come up with a javascript routine to scan the select and count the number of actually visible options on screen and set the size attribute on the element manually after the page hits the client.

Does anyone know a better way to control this scrolling issue. Is there a way to tell .Net or the Listbox to do this automatically? Being that i'm going to be modifying a .Net control client side I fear this is going to cause post back issues later if I have to do any. I don't really trust having to recalculate where every option is on/or off screen any time dimensions change. I've googled around for several days and it seems like people have similar problems, but it's either with postbacks or they already know how many rows there are going to be, or they're adding/removing/ rows causing redraws. Is javascript really my only answer and if so how is that going to screw with my session states?

EDIT 1: Adding Code

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="main" class="flexRow">
      <div id="listWrap" class="flexCol w25p">
        <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lstContents"></asp:ListBox>
        <div class="flexRow">
          <button value="New">New</button>
          <button value="Del">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content" class="flexCol"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CodeBehind:

```
//Global Variable
List<Content> ContentList { get;set; }

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstContents.Items.Clear();
    var ctx = HttpContent.Current;
    using (var s = new SQL(Conn))
    using (var r = (IDataReader)s.ExecProc(QType.Reader, "GetContent"))
        while (r.Read()) {
            ContentList.Add(new Content(r));

    var orderedSet = from c in ContentList
                     orderby c.ID
                     select c;

    foreach (var c in orderedSet)
        lstContents.Items.Add(new ListItem(c.Name, c.ID));

    lstContents.SlectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Single;
    lstContents.AutoPostBack = false;
    lstContents.Rows = 44; //ContentList.Count; //2; //1; //0; //999999;
}
```

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you post your (listbox) code

Comment: For anyone who comes across this later, I ended up ditching the listbox and going with a fully client side control and an ajax loader. Wazz's suggestion while workable, just required a lot more additions and management overhead than a pure <ul> with some css (which was needed anyway), and an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You lost me at "...this also causes my event.target object to point back to the select element instead of the clicked option element..."

I got to the end though. :) I think you're talking about maintaining scroll position in the listbox.

I use the code below with updatepanels. Maybe you can adapt it.

```
// To maintain scroll position of a listbox inside an update panel.
// Make sure this script is after the scriptmanager.
// Source: http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewfrederick/archive/2008/03/04/maintain-scroll-position-after-asynchronous-postback.aspx

var xPos, yPos;
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    if ($get('lst') !== null) {
        // Get X and Y positions of scrollbar before the partial postback
        xPos = $get('lst').scrollLeft;
        yPos = $get('lst').scrollTop;
    }
}

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    if ($get('lst') !== null) {
        // Set X and Y positions back to the scrollbar after the partial postback
        $get('lst').scrollLeft = xPos;
        $get('lst').scrollTop = yPos;
    }
}

prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
```

Comment: Do you only use listboxes with update panels? I'm not, so I'm kind of wondering if I'm using it wrong now (I've seen a lot of UpdatePanel suggestions while googling this).

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. After the listbox into an update panel, adding the script manager and putting in your js code, its still acting like I described above.

Comment: You can definitely use listboxes without update panels. For the code above (with u.p.), you have to change `'lst'` to the ID of your listbox (6 different occurences in the code).